My softener is located in a pump house with no drain
My softener is located in a pump house with no drain so it discharges on ground and is killing grass . My thought is to dig a large hole (2-3 cubic foot) and fill with limestone then drain softener into it. Will this correct problem ?

You'll still be leaching salt solution into the soil.

It might be a short therm solution

This may be better answered by a gardening or horticulture specialist and be dependant on your location.   I had my softener drain to an area  planted with plants that were tolerant and even dependant on some saltwater. So, not issues for me. You are probably different. If in Florida or the deep south along the coast maybe not.

It's killing grass because it's salty.
accept it, move it, do without, or install a drain.

It depends on how much liquid is coming out.  I would aim for a hole, larger in area and depth. So, the water has a chance to pool and then  evaporate.

A water softener flush can (potentially) put out quite a few gallons of salty water, so not sure how well that would evaporate between uses, and there would also be a lot of eventual salt buildup after multiple cycles of evaporation.

Without knowing what else is around, it's hard to offer a specific solution.  Your best bet would be to run it to a known good drain somewhere, whether that's via underground, or elsewhere.  But keep in mind that the salty flush water can be detrimental to metal things over the long term, so you need to be careful where it goes, and where you can legally discharge the output.
